# square graph L shaped implementation

Tags: c, graph

if I'm here it's because my humble logic and debugging skills fails me.

Please forgive any grammar/spelling mistakes, I try do do my best but this is not my mother tongue.

I'm actually trying to do a graph/diagram being a set of nodes containing up,bottom,left,right nodes and x,y position for each node.

To do so I decided to assign nodes on the y axis and then creating a node at the right of the bottomest and then iterating this procedure whilst x < the size of my graph.

Then I'm freeing the last bottomest rightest node because it's out of the graph I want to build.
Thereafter I want to link the elements of my graph that are not already linked to their adjacent nodes.

And when trying to access the left element of the rightest bottomest node, I get some segfault !!

For those for whose this is not clear, here what's I'm trying to do (for a 3*3 graph) :

http://imgur.com/bPi3Au2,kCInKDs#1

and here's where I am so far (for a 3*3 graph) :

http://imgur.com/bPi3Au2,kCInKDs#0

Here's the code : (this file is a .h)

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct s_ftree
{
    struct s_ftree *up;
    struct s_ftree *bottom;
    struct s_ftree *left;
    struct s_ftree *right;
    int x;
    int y;
}       t_ftree;

t_ftree *node_constructor(int x, int y)
{
    t_ftree *node = (t_ftree*)malloc(sizeof(t_ftree));
    node->x = x;
    node->y = y;
    node->up = NULL;
    node->bottom = NULL;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    return (node);
}

t_ftree *graph_constructor(int graph_size) /*Main fucnction, this is called from
                                           a compiled .c file */
{

    int x;
    int y;

    x = 0;
    y = 0;

    t_ftree *curr = node_constructor(0, 0);
while(x < graph_size)
{
    while (y < graph_size)
    {
        curr->up = node_constructor(x, ++y);
        curr->up->bottom = curr;
        curr = curr->up;
    }
    while (--y > 0)
        curr = curr->bottom;
    x++;
    curr->right = node_constructor(x, y);
    curr->right->left = curr;
    curr = curr->right;
}

--x;
curr = curr->left; /* Suppressing the last bottom right element */
free(curr->right);
curr->right = NULL;
while(--x > 0)
{
    curr = curr->left; /* Segfault here !! */ 
}

/* other treatments here */

    return (curr);
}
```

So I'm trying to acess an element not allocated, I don't know if I'm misrepresentating the way I'm trying to do the graph and the actual position I'm in when assigning curr->left to curr or if that's a dumb error coming from brain damage :/

Aside from that, buildind this kind of graphs in a L-shaped way is the only way I found for now but I'd be interested as to read of other methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having trouble spotting how or why you end up with an extra node to delete, but it should definitely be possible to avoid that.

On a separate note, have you considered constructing all the nodes first, then initializing all the links?  It temporarily uses a bit more memory, but it could be easier to write and to reason about.  Something like this, perhaps:

```
t_ftree *graph_constructor(int graph_size) {
    /* here and below, graph_size is assumed > 0 */
    t_ftree **grid = malloc(graph_size * graph_size * sizeof(t_ftree *));
    t_ftree *node00;
    int x, y;

    if (!grid) {
        return NULL;
    }

    for (x = 0; x < graph_size; x += 1) {
        for (y = 0; y < graph_size; y += 1) {
            grid[x * graph_size + y] = node_constructor(x, y);
        }
    }

    for (x = 0; x < graph_size - 1; x += 1) {
        for (y = 0; y < graph_size; y += 1) {
            grid[x * graph_size + y]->right = grid[(x + 1) * graph_size + y];
        }
    }
    for (x = 1; x < graph_size; x += 1) {
        for (y = 0; y < graph_size; y += 1) {
            grid[x * graph_size + y]->left = grid[(x - 1) * graph_size + y];
        }
    }
    for (x = 0; x < graph_size; x += 1) {
        for (y = 0; y < graph_size - 1; y += 1) {
            grid[x * graph_size + y]->up = grid[x * graph_size + y + 1];
        }
    }
    for (x = 0; x < graph_size; x += 1) {
        for (y = 1; y < graph_size; y += 1) {
            grid[x * graph_size + y]->down = grid[x * graph_size + y - 1];
        }
    }

    node00 = *grid;
    free(grid);
    return node00;
}
```

Note also that although the `typedef` may reasonably live in a header (.h) file, and you might also put function prototypes in such a header, the function implementations should be in ordinary C source files (.c), not in header files.

Anyway, if you prefer your approach to constructing the graph, then why not at least retain an external pointer to node (0, 0) as an extra variable in function `graph_constructor()`, instead of walking the graph to find it?

Comment: Thanks for your insight and your advices about file organisation. Even thought I just debugged my implementation (while(--x > 0) become while(--x >= 0)) , I'll try and use your method of the array. As to an external pointer it would mean the function would loose in ergonomy as the user (me) would have to remember to build a node, initialize it's x & y to 0 and then pass it to the function. I prefer all in one functions, especially those going into an utilities header.